# Were any Mishnaic passages found in the Dead-sea scrolls?

Tags: history, mishna

As I can see, there were some [Halachic/Legal passages found in the Dead-see scrolls](https://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive/search#q=composition_type_parent_en:%27Legal%20Texts%27).

[image]

From the archeological and historical findings, I've understood that these sects kept Teffilin, Shabbes, Kashrus, Tevilah, sacrifices, Templaic works, Yom Kippur, the Three Regolim, and more. It's impossible that their Law didn't overlap the Pharisees' Mishnah in any Halacha.

Were any Mishnaic/Beraitah passages found in the Dead-sea scrolls?

Comment: No, to my knowledge. It's evident from what was found that these people kept halacha in a manner different than how the Tannaim kept it.

Comment: Don't see how that would be possible. Aside from the fact the dead sea scroll sect was antagonistic to the those who lived by the Mishna and Briaisa, the Mishna and Braisa itself had not been formally written yet  at the time the dead sea scrolls are believed to have been written.

Comment: @Harel13 I think it is impossible that a Jewish sect would not keep some passages from the oral law.

Comment: @Schmerel Those guys kept Teffilin, Shabbes, Kashrus, Tevilah, sacrifices, Yom Kippur, It's impossible that they didn't overlap the Mishnah in any Halacha.

Comment: @AlBerko evidently you haven't read much about what historians think about this sect. Also, on your comment to Schmerel, there's a difference between overlapping and actually quoting/paralleling. Which are you looking for?

Comment: To clarify a little more, this sect was not a Hellenistic one. So they kept mitzvot d'oraita. However, they were not aligned with the Pharisees - the opposite. In one scroll a scathing letter to the Jerusalem leadership was found. They were not happy with the halachic direction followed in Jerusalem, to put it lightly.

Comment: @Harel13 I think it is universally accepted that since Teffilin, Shechita, Tevilah, Shabbos are not detailed in the Torah, they HAD to have some kind of Oral Law, which should overlap with ours at least partially.

Comment: @AlBerko I don't get why you expect that they "should" overlap. I recommend doing some reading on the subject. Here's an interesting essay that was published in Tarbitz not long after they discovered one of the halachic DSS (you can access it for free if you create an account in the NLI website): https://www.jstor.org/stable/23598595?refreqid=excelsior%3A1b3d915ed733dcdd0b99f72b789146c2. And here's a lecture by Rabbi Prof. Shnayer Leiman: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/732090/dr-shnayer-leiman/dead-sea-scrolls/. Just some places to start.

Answer (score 2):

In the MMT scroll, that is, Miktzat Maaseh Torah, there are several points describing what they maintain the folk in Yerushalayim are doing wrong. As I recall, there is a point that overlaps the Shammai position, in terms of nitzok. See page 171 in this pdf:

https://as.nyu.edu/content/dam/nyu-as/faculty/documents/NominalismRealism.pdf

Note that this is not the same as a passage that overlaps a passage in Mishnah / braytot.

Comment: Thank you very interesting.